# Render duplicate records from a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, render, partials

I'm passing an array of IDs into a .find and returning a collection.  The array should contain duplicate IDs. However, the .find method is excluding the duplicate IDs from the collection.

I actually want the duplicate records returned from the search and then rendered into partials.

If I create another array of just the duplicate IDs and concatenate the two arrays, I've got a collection that includes the duplicate IDs. However, when rendering the collection with partials, it does not render two partials when there's a duplicate ID.

`= render partial: 'shows/show', collection: @shows, cached: true`

The reason I'd like to do this:

I am rendering partials of concert listings. Under COVID, a lot of concerts are changing dates. I would like to display the concert listing on the original date of the concert (with a message saying it's been postponed) as well as on the new date.

Schema:

```
create_table "shows", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
t.date "date"
t.datetime "doors_open_at"
t.datetime "dinner_starts_at"
t.datetime "dinner_ends_at"
t.datetime "show_starts_at"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "venue_id"
t.integer "seating_chart_id"
t.integer "artist_id"
t.datetime "back_end_on_sale_at"
t.datetime "front_end_on_sale_at"
t.datetime "back_end_off_sale_at"
t.datetime "front_end_off_sale_at"
t.decimal "deposit_amount", precision: 8, scale: 2
t.string "type", null: false
t.datetime "deactivated_at"
t.integer "deactivated_by_id"
t.text "additional_text"
t.string "googleads"
t.boolean "deactive"
t.date "original_date"
t.index ["artist_id"], name: "index_shows_on_artist_id"
t.index ["deactivated_by_id"], name: "index_shows_on_deactivated_by_id"
t.index ["seating_chart_id"], name: "index_shows_on_seating_chart_id"
t.index ["venue_id"], name: "index_shows_on_venue_id"
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on 1) why there are duplicates? 2) why you want to display them? I am not arguing against your design or desire there just might be suitable ways to go about this with a bit more detail e.g. (the duplicates are because there are 2 shows in one day. This can be solved by changing the query a bit to cause the duplicates to exist in the collection)

Comment: Thank you for the questions I have edited the post

Comment: Can you provide some portion of your schema showing how the dates are related to the show?

Comment: Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sure that helps. I will see what I can put together. I am assuming you want to display them by date such that "Show 1" appears 2020-10-01 and says postponed to 2021-02-03 and then have it also show up in position 2021-02-03. Correct? The easiest way to do this would be to create a new `Show` and link the original to it e.g. add a `postponement_id`, add `belongs_to :postponement, class: "Show"`, this would make the listing and the relation simpler. `Show.where(id: YOUR_IDs).or(postponement_id: Show.where(id: YOUR_IDs).select(:postponement_id)).order(:date)`

Comment: I think that would create another issue - when a show is postponed, all the tickets that have been sold go with it.  If a new show was to be created, I'd need to transfer all of the ticket information to the new show